# Pytest runs my tests while collecting them

Tags: python, electron, pytest

I wrote some tests for an Electron exe app. With Pytest, in the collection phase, the tests are executed, instead of just collected.

Python 3.10.2 for Windows
Pytest 7.2.0
Chromedriver 98.0.4758.109

I wrote some tests for an Electron exe app. With Pytest, in the collection phase, the tests are executed, instead of just collected. All the tests begin with something like:

```
class Test():

def test(self):
   wait, autho, driver = initialSetup(self)
```

and are ran with:

```
test3 = Test()
test3.test()
```

In the collection phase, Pytest shows messages like these in the VSCode terminal:

```
<Module tests/test_SimplePurchaseWithLoyaltySliderDineIn.py>
  <Class Test>
    <Function test>
<Module tests/test_SimplePurchaseWithLoyaltySliderTakeOut.py>
  <Class Test>
    <Function test>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are some substantial formatting issues in your posted code. If that reflects your actual code, it would probably just result in syntax errors.

Comment: Are you sure the are executed and not just listed?

Comment: Absolutely. Every test collected is immediately run. And after the collection is finished, the tests start again.

Comment: Well, that is certainly strange. There is not enough information in your question to get any idea how that can happen, though.